# update case statement not working in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE TABLE  #@TTableName
(Grp varchar(100),
TotalFB int,
Excellent int,
ExcellentPerc float,
AAvg int,
AAvgPerc float,
Average int,
AveragePerc float,
BAvg int,
BAvgPerc float,
Poor int,
PoorPerc float
)

INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Parking',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Enquiry',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Registration',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('WaitingTime',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Pharmacy',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Laboratory',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Radiology',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Receptionist',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Nurse',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Consultants',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Others',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Cleanliness',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Signage',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAvgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Ambience',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #@TTableName(Grp,TotalFB,Excellent,ExcellentPerc,AAvg,AAVgPerc,Average,AveragePerc,BAvg,BAvgPerc,Poor,PoorPerc) values ('Lift',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

begin
declare Code_Cursor insensitive cursor for 
    select *
    FROM FB
    where EDate >= convert(datetime,@FrDate) and EDate <= convert(datetime,@ToDate) --between convert(datetime,@FrDate) and convert(datetime,@ToDate) 
end

Open Code_Cursor
fetch next from Code_Cursor into @Parking,@Enquiry,@Registration,@WaitingTime,@Pharmacy,@Laboratory,@Radiology,@Receptionist,@Nurse,@Consultants,@Others,@Cleanliness,@Signage,@Ambience,@Lift,@AnyOther
while @@fetch_status =0
begin

UPDATE #@TTableName SET

    CASE @Parking

        WHEN  5 THEN Excellent=Excellent + 1 
        WHEN  4 THEN AAvg=AAvg + 1
        WHEN  3 THEN Average=Average + 1
        WHEN  2 THEN BAvg=BAvg + 1
        WHEN  1 THEN Poor=Poor + 1

    END
where @Grp='Parking'

fetch next from Code_Cursor into @Parking,@Enquiry,@Registration,@WaitingTime,@Pharmacy,@Laboratory,@Radiology,@Receptionist,@Nurse,@Consultants,@Others,@Cleanliness,@Signage,@Ambience,@Lift,@AnyOther
end
close Code_Cursor
deallocate Code_Cursor

--UPDATE #@TTableName SET Meddesc = (SELECT Description
--from Medtype  WHERE #@TTableName.cardtype = MedType.Type)
--FROM #@TTableName,MedType

select * from #@TTableName
GO
```

where update case statement gives error like Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FBCount, Line 84
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FBCount, Line 96
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.

Please help me

Thank you in advance

shaila

Comment: but how it is please tell

Comment: It looks like you're looking for something like `PIVOT` which would do the `SUM()` and shift from rows to columns in a single query.

Comment: Also, possibly to help your thinking in the future - `CASE` is an *expression*. Its various `WHEN`/`ELSE` clauses are used to compute a single result (per row, if used in a query) which becomes the *value* of the whole expression.

Comment: please consider accepting questions that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt doesn't work because that UPDATE syntax is not defined
.

You could do it like this:

```
UPDATE #@TTableName 
SET 
    Excellent =  CASE WHEN @Parking = 5 THEN Excellent + 1 ELSE Excellent END,
    AAvg      =  CASE WHEN @Parking = 4 THEN AAvg + 1 ELSE AAvg END,
    -- etc....

where @Grp = 'Parking'
```

[But to be honest there must be a better way than using a cursor]